# How to specify multiple search columns for wp list table search

Tags: search, wp-list-table

I have working search for a created `wp_list_table`. But i like to know how I can search in more than one column.

My current my working search setup in a Visitor class

```
//search something
$searchcol= array(
    'visitorCompany',
    'visitorName',
    'visitorEmail'
    );  
$search = !empty($_REQUEST["s"]) ?  mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["s"]) : '';
//$search = preg_replace( "^$\**(.*)\**$?#", "*$1*", $_REQUEST["s"] );
if(!empty($_REQUEST["s"])) {$query .= ' WHERE '.$searchcol[1].' LIKE "%'.$search.'%"';}
```

here I just searching in the `visitorName` column, but i like to use the `$searchcol` to search in.

A foreach loop

```
foreach( $searchcol as $col) {
    if(!empty($_REQUEST["s"])) {$query .= ' WHERE '.$col.' LIKE "%'.$search.'%"';}
}
```

didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Ok i see my WHERE mistake

I made this working solution doesn't look pretty

```
$i =0;
        foreach( $searchcol as $col) {
            if($i==0) {
                $sqlterm = 'WHERE';
            } else {
                $sqlterm = 'OR';
            }
            if(!empty($_REQUEST["s"])) {$query .=  ' '.$sqlterm.' '.$col.' LIKE "%'.$search.'%"';}
            $i++;
        }
```